# Nativescript application crash on start up in android device

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developed android and iOS application using Nativescript. Now I started the project migration process. I got the crash issue. The crash log like:

[image]

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@mashdog/nativescript-accordion": "^7.0.6",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^12.2.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.0.2",
    "@nativescript/iqkeyboardmanager": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^13.2.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^2.0.4",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^4.1.2",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-youtubeplayer": "^4.1.4",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-phone": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-ripple": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-store-ratings": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^2.0.24",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^10.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this issue? please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: A good place to start is to follow the suggestion in your console output and run tns debug android --debug-brk to see if you can get more error information